# overflow hidden with no breaking words

Tags: html, overflow

```html
<div style="width:120px; border:solid 1px #f00;">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

I have code like this and i would like to all text be in one line and cut to 120px so i need hide text but i want text in one line (when i set overflow:visible I want to have one line)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="width:120px; border:solid 1px #f00; overflow: hidden;  white-space: nowrap;">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

This should work.